# Keeping leading spaces in C

Tags: c, string

I'm having this simple problem that I can't get over with.

```
int B;
char *a = (char*)malloc(1000*sizeof(char);

scanf("%[^\n]s", a);
printf("%c\n", a[0]);
B = strlen(a);
printf("%d\n", B);
```

If I put an entry like:

```
"   abc  "
```

a[0] = 'a' and B = 5 (the "abc" plus the last two spaces).  I want to count the first three spaces, how do I do it?

Comment: Explain what your `scanf` line of code does.

Comment: `int spaces; scanf(" %n%[^\n]", &spaces, a);`

Comment: Use `%[ ]` to read a sequence of spaces.

Comment: Just use `fgets` to read the line, and then count the spaces.

Comment: Do you mean "count the spaces" as in you want to include them in the result? Or do you literally want to count them?

Comment: Note that the `s` after the scanset `%[^\n]` is a literal `s` that should appear in the data — except it can never be matched because the scanset only leaves a newline as the next character, so the `s` doesn't match.  Also, you need to test the return result from `scanf()`.  And, especially when you're worried about spaces, you should print the input data with something like `printf("data [%s]\n", a);` so you can see the start and end of the string.  Printing what the program actually got is a simple but invaluable technique for checking that you and the program are in agreement.

Comment: The code you posted would give `a[0] = ' '` and `B = 7` for the given input. If you are still having trouble please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply read the entire line using `fgets()` instead of using `scanf()`, which generally skips whitespace unless you explicitly capture it.

```
int B;
char *a = malloc(1000 * sizeof*a); /* don't cast malloc */

if (fgets(a, 1000, stdin) == NULL) {
    fputs("Could not read input\n", stdout);
}
else {
    printf("%c\n", a[0]);
    B = strlen(a);
    printf("%d\n", B);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This solve some of the problems. I thought fgets ignored white spaces on the strlen count.

Comment: @Tricolor `strlen()` will count all characters leading up to the terminating `\0`. It does not skip any characters in between. `fgets()` is different than `scanf()` in that `scanf()` is designed for parsing certain inputs whereas `fgets()` is designed to read an entire line from an input stream. `scanf()` should only be used for string inputs on select occasions. Otherwise, `fgets()` is probably what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to trim the leading space, you can try this:

```
void trim_left(char *p);
int main()
{
  int B;
  char *a = (char*)malloc(1000*sizeof(char));

  scanf("%[^\n]s", a);
  printf("%c\n", a[0]);
  trim_left(a);
  B = strlen(a);
  printf("%d\n", B);
  printf("a = %s\n", a);
  return 0;
}

void trim_left(char *p) {
  int i = 0;
  while (p[i] && isspace(p[i])) {
    i++;
  }
  memmove(p, p+i, strlen(p+i));
  p[strlen(p+i)] = '\0';
}
```